# JAXB unmarshall with namespaces and prefix

Tags: java, soap, namespaces, jaxb

I am using JAXB to parse xml elements from the SOAP response. I have defined POJO classes for the xml elements. I have tested pojo classes without namespace and prefix its working fine .Though when i am trying to parse with namespaces and prefix facing the following exception.Requirement is to parse the input from SOAPMessage Object

`javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{}Envelope>`

Tried to fix by creating @XMLSchema for the package in package-info.java and located this file in package folder.Can any one guide me to move forward?

[Referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483699/unmarshaling-of-soap-response-with-namespace-prefix) this posts but didn help me .

**EDITED :XMLSchema**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (
    xmlns = {  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "env", 
                 namespaceURI="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
      @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="ns3", namespaceURI="http://www.xxxx.com/ncp/oomr/dto/")
    }
  )
package com.one.two;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you configured the namespace in @XMLSchema?

Comment: What about the Envelope element? Is it properly namespaced?

Comment: Ultimately do you want to map the envelope to objects or just the body?  Here is how you could map to the middle of a SOAP document: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan i have referred many of your blogs regarding xml.Should i wanna create the file from the SOAPMessage Object? is possible to parse the middle elements from the Object ? yes i want to read the elements from the body ,,

Answer (score 22):

This can be done without modifying the generated JAXB code using standard SOAPMessage class. I wrote about this [here](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/707) and [here](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/711)

It's a little fiddly but works correctly.

### Marshalling

```
Farm farm = new Farm();
farm.getHorse().add(new Horse());
farm.getHorse().get(0).setName("glue factory");
farm.getHorse().get(0).setHeight(BigInteger.valueOf(123));

Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Farm.class).createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(farm, document);
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
soapMessage.getSOAPBody().addDocument(document);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(outputStream);
String output = new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

### Unmarshalling

```
String example =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header /><soapenv:Body><ns2:farm xmlns:ns2=\"http://adamish.com/example/farm\"><horse height=\"123\" name=\"glue factory\"/></ns2:farm></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
        new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes()));
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Farm.class).createUnmarshaller();
Farm farm = (Farm)unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());
```

Comment: Great answer, one minor addition for anyone who might be interested: if you don't know the exact class will be that's in the SOAP envelope, but you do know the envelope, initialize the unmarshaller like this: `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.my.package").createUnmarshaller()`

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I kept getting errors until I explicitly told the unmarshaller (again) what class to unmarshall to.  `Farm farm = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument(), Farm.class).getValue();`

Answer (score 15):

Here is how you can handle your use cae:

### If You Need to Map the `Envelope` Element

**package-info**

Typically you would use the `@XmlSchema` as follows.  Using the `namespace` and `elementFormDefault` properties like I've done means that all data mapped to XML elements unless otherwise mapped will belong to the `http://www.xxxx.com/ncp/oomr/dto/` namespace.  The information specified in `xmlns` is for XML schema generation altough some JAXB implementations use this to determine the preferred prefix for a namespace when marshalling (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html).

```
@XmlSchema (
    namespace="http://www.xxxx.com/ncp/oomr/dto/",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {  
        @XmlNs(prefix = "env", namespaceURI="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
        @XmlNs(prefix="whatever", namespaceURI="http://www.xxxx.com/ncp/oomr/dto/")
    }
  )
package com.one.two;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Envelope**

If within the `com.one.two` you need to map to elements from a namespace other than `http://www.xxxx.com/ncp/oomr/dto/` then you need to specify it in the `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` annotations.

```
package com.one.two;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Envelope", namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Envelope {

    @XmlElement(name="Body", namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    private Body body;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

### If You Just Want to Map the Body

You can use a StAX parser to parse the message and advance to the payload portion and unmarshal from there:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class UnmarshalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/blog/stax/middle/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
        xsr.nextTag();
        while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("return")) {
            xsr.nextTag();
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Customer> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Customer.class);
        xsr.close();
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: @TheUnusual - `package-info.java` goes in the same directory as the other Java source for the same package.

Comment: Thanks for your response@Blaise Doughan.

Comment: Blaise, thanks so much for this post, it helped me a lot. In my case my SOAP envelope contained elements with text, in which case the call to getLocalName() was throwing an exception on invalid content. I made a minor change to your while loop to get past this:
<code>
 while (xsr.hasNext()){
  xsr.next();
  if (xsr.hasName() && xsr.getLocalName().equals("return"))
   break;
 }
</code>

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add onto the existing answers -- while unmarshalling if the XML document is not namespace aware you might receive an error: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://some.url";, local:"someOperation")

If this is the case you can simply use a different method on the unmarshaller:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourObject.class).createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<YourObject> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument(), YourObject.class);
YourObject yo = element.getValue();
```