# XML document to SOAPEnvelope Object

Tags: java, axis

Right now I have a XML document, I need to parse it into SOAPEnvelope object (apache axis 1.4) using JAVA. Any idea how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a JAXB approach. 
Everything is detailed on that link:

[JAXB unmarshall with namespaces and prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395400/jaxb-unmarshall-with-namespaces-and-prefix)