# While loop not looping through whole xml string when unmarshalling

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

I've a xml string that I unmarshall but it only returns the first part. I believe my while loop isn't correct.

```
while(xsr.hasNext()){   
     if(xsr.isStartElement() && "list".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {           
          break;        
     }       
     xsr.next(); 
}
```

My Xml string is similar to this -

```
<list><name>Ben_1</name><assign>trac</assign></list><list><name>John</name><assign>task</assign></list>
```

When I do a get request from postman, it only returns

```
{
  "list": {
    "name": "Ben_1",
    "assign": "trac"
  }
}
```

I tried methods from these(and other) posts - [JAXB unmarshall with namespaces and prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395400/jaxb-unmarshall-with-namespaces-and-prefix)

My expected answer should be

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Ben_1",
      "assign": "trac"
    },
    {
      "name": "John",
      "assign": "task"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is `xsr`? where is the processing code ?

Comment: Did you notice that your reference Postman shows JSON, and your expected answer is JSON? Where is the connection to parsing an XML string?

Comment: @jhamon this is xsr "XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml)" My bad, I didn't upload it, but it's just like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401316/14839942

Comment: @Queeg That's in my parsing class, the while statement I mentioned is where I'm trying to traverse through the xml string. My class is similar to this right here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401316/14839942

Comment: And I suppose `xif` is an `XMLInputFactory`? Instead of making us guess, why don't you show your code?

Comment: Your XML doesn't have any root element. It's a forest, not a tree. Is that intentional?

Comment: `xsr.isStartElement() && "list".equals(xsr.getLocalName())` will be `true` as soon as it sees the first `<list>` tag, before it processes any data whatsoever, so that is completely wrong.

Comment: I changed the code to iterate as long as `xsr.hasNext()` and after Ben_1 it throws: `Exception javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,54]
Message: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.` You need an outer XML tag, like: `<lists><list>...Ben_1...</list><list>...John...</list></lists>`

Comment: @DavidConrad my bad, I'm new to all this so I apologize for not adding all of my code, in my while loop, instead of 'break;' I added continue but I was not sure how to make it stop. So if I do add a outer XML tag, will this logic work? if not, please share the code you implemented. Thanks and again I'm sorry for such a poor post.

Comment: I've added an answer with the code I used. There is still a problem with your logic in that it breaks as soon as it sees a `<list>` start element.

Comment: @DavidConrad This is what I was looking for!! Thank you! it prints everything and then I'm running into the issue you mentioned.
Were you referring to this error? 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: reader must be on a START_ELEMENT event, not a 8 event. 
I changed my xml string to <Env><lists><list><name><assign></assign></name></list></lists></Env>
Is there a specific way to stop parsing when at the end of the xml string?

Comment: In my answer I looped `while (xsr.hasNext()) ...` That should stop at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this XML there is no one top-level element. There are two `list` elements:

```
<list>
    <name>Ben_1</name>
    <assign>trac</name>
</list>
<list>
    <name>John</name>
    <assign>task</name>
</list>
```

In this XML, there is a single top-level element, `lists`:

```
<lists>
    <list>
        <name>Ben_1</name>
        <assign>trac</name>
    </list>
    <list>
        <name>John</name>
        <assign>task</name>
    </list>
</lists>
```

If you were to diagram it in a [tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) it would be a single tree, whereas for the previous example, there would be one tree for each `list`: a "forest." The `XMLStreamReader` requires a tree, not a forest.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

String xml = "<lists><list><name>Ben_1</name><assign>trac</assign></list>" +
    "<list><name>John</name><assign>task</assign></list></lists>";

var xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
var xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));

while (xsr.hasNext()) {
    if (xsr.hasText()) {
        System.out.println(xsr.getText());
    }
    xsr.next();
}
```

Given the "forest" XML, this code will throw an `XMLStreamException` with the message "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." when it gets to the second `<list>` tag, but given the "tree" XML it will output:

```
Ben_1
trac
John
task
```

I don't know how you intend to handle this data but this should get you past the point you are currently stuck at.

Comment: This fixed my initial problem, now it displays everything in my xml, but when it needs to convert xml, it throws this error -  java.lang.IllegalStateException: reader must be on a START_ELEMENT event, not a 8 event... 
I've tried messing with the code but no good, do you know what that error could mean?

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder I don't, and without seeing your code, there's no way to tell. I suggest you ask another question and include the code that produces the exception in it.

Comment: Do we need a loop for going through the xml or the XMLStreamReader does that part? Also, is there a way to point to start element when it's gone through the whole xml? What I'm confused on is that whether we need a loop or not when converting to Json

Comment: We need a loop, but I think your other question was using JAXB, which will loop itself. You can't make it point back to the start element but you can just create a new XSR off of the same source.